# Variable value not updating via method call

Tags: c#, .net

This smells like a scoping issue with my variable however moving it does not seem to help.  Here is a very simple example.  I create the currentDay variable.  I set it's value.  I then call another method which should change the value of currentDay, but it never changes.  Just Monday morning blindness?

```
void Main()
{
    SetScheduleTicketsDate();
}

public static void SetScheduleTicketsDate()
{
    DateTime currentDay = DateTime.Now;
    SchedulePatchGroup(currentDay);
    Console.WriteLine(currentDay);
}

private static void SchedulePatchGroup(DateTime currentDay)
{
    currentDay = currentDay.AddDays(10);
}
```

Comment: What if you change it to `return currentDay.AddDays(10);`?

Comment: Also, I believe that `DateTime` is a value-type, not a reference type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assigning a parameter will not propagate to the caller unless you use `ref` or `out`.

Usually that's a code smell; your method should probably just return the updated object anyways.

```
public static void SetScheduleTicketsDate()
{
    DateTime currentDay = DateTime.Now;
    currentDay = SchedulePatchGroup(currentDay);
    Console.WriteLine(currentDay);
}

private static DateTime SchedulePatchGroup(DateTime currentDay)
{
    return currentDay.AddDays(10);
}
```

Just using `currentDay.AddDays(10)` won't do anything either since DateTime is a value type; `AddDays` does not mutate the current instance and instead returns a new one.

Comment: Perhaps would be worth noting in your answer that `DateTime` is not a reference type (which is maybe where the confusion is).

Comment: Yeah, I would have expected it to mutate the current value like other variables.  This makes sense.  My SchedulePatchGroup does its thing, coming up with a new currentDay and then returns it rather than directly setting it.